# trying to learn python tkinter. but when i run the following code the tkinter window does not open[error: "RMS" is not defined"] "

Tags: python, tkinter

error: "RMS" is not defined[image]tkinter window is not opening

```
    from tkinter import*
    class RMS:
    def __init__(self,root):
    self.root=root
    self.root.title("Result Management System")
    self.root.geometry("1350x700+0+0")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    obj=RMS(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation is wrong. look closely at every line

Comment: Please provide your code as text so we can easily run it without needing to type it in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation in the code is wrong because of which ***main*** is being checked inside the class definition.

The indentation should be as below:

```
from tkinter import *
class RMS:
    self.root = root
    ....
    self.root.geometry("...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TK()
    obj = RMS(root)
    ....
```

Comment: You are missing underscore `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @toyotaSupra. I will update it.